# Can't Delete Unwanted Code Without Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android

I'm requesting a user's facebook friends who use my app, then querying the database for each one to see if they are already friends in my app.

I altered this code from one that made an http request. I don't need to make an http request but I can't get rid of this line or it causes a null pointer exception for my facebook response.

Here is the code I want to get rid of:

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_friend_status, "POST", params);
```

And it causes a null pointer exception for this line:

```
products = FriendResponse.getJSONArray("data");
```

In eclipse it even says that "The value of the local variable json is not used", but it seems like some part of that line is required for my facebook response to work?

**Here are the bigger code pieces:**

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String fbid = fbID;

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // I don't want this, but when I remove it, FriendResponse.toString causes null pointer exception
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_friend_status, "POST", params);

        try {

            // getting JSON Array from facebook response
                products = FriendResponse.getJSONArray("data");
```

**makeMeRequest:**

```
private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
// Make an API call to get user data and define a 
// new callback to handle the response.

Request friendsrequest = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session, 
        new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
        // If the response is successful
        if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
            if (users != null) {

                FriendResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();

            }
        }
        if (response.getError() != null) {
            // Handle errors, will do so later.
        }
    }
});
friendsrequest.executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: ```FriendResponse``` does not seem to have been initialized. Also, I see that you are initializing this variable in ```makMeRequest``` function. This function is never called I suppose

Comment: That makes sense, except that everything works perfectly if I leave in that JSONObject line, and only fails when I remove it. It's quite baffling to me. I've been trying to figure it out for weeks!

Comment: See who is callling the ```makeMeRequest``` method from your ide.

Comment: I suspect that some listener is calling that method after your method call

Comment: I haven't solved the issue yet, but you've got me on the right track. FriendResponse is not being sent where it should be. Thanks!